# Need to filter the existing queryset

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

I need to filter further the existing queryset in flask sqlalchemy.
Example :
Let Users table has 10000 records in database ...
users=Users.query.filter(is_active=True)---got 1000 records...
Now I want to use those 1000 records only and want to check if user's location is 'Hyderabad' ...Instead of checking in entire 10000 records, it should check in existing 1000 records only so that it improves performance .

I think I have clearly mentioned the problem statement ..

Thank you in advance...

Comment: This approach shouldn't be necessary.  If you create an index over `is_active` and `location` the RDBMS should generate an efficient query.

Answer (score 0):

You can chain the filters like this using the `and_` or `_or`

something like this

```py
from sqlalchemy import and_, or_, not_

query = meta.Session.query(User).filter(
    and_(
        User.is_active.like(search_variable_like),
        User.location.like(search_variable_location)
    )
)
```

**Update**
get all users records that meet your criteria

```py
users = User.query.filter(is_active=True).all()

# now got the 1k records, check for location
hyderabad_users = []

for user in users:
   if user.location == 'Hyderabad':
      hyderabad_users.append(user)
```

Comment: but this will again check in entire table data.. what I want is like, it should check in existing records only